# Class that uses dynamically generated array

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, dynamically-generated

Trying to make a class that can change the contents of a specific element in a dynamically created 2 dimensional array of strings.

So I have a program that creates a 2d array dynamically and later on I want to have a class that takes that array as its argument, along with 2 integers that will be the indexes of a specific element. Later on I'll have it swap the content of that element and scan other elements of the array that it wants to swap it with. For now I'm struggling with even having the class take that array as its argument. I know I'll have to do this by reference and not by value, since the array will be dynamically created, but it seems I am doing it wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Example {
    int x, y;
    string** chart;
public:

    Example(int i, int j,string **arr);
    void print() const { cout << x << y << chart[x][y] << endl; }

};

Example::Example(int i, int j,string **arr) {
    x = i;
    y = j;
    **chart = **arr;
}

int main() {

    string chart[7][7]; //to make the experiment simpler I haven't 
                        //made the array dynamically generated yet
                        //but it will be later

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (chart[i][j] == "")
                chart[i][j].insert(0, 3, '  ');
        }
    }

    chart[6][5] = "EXA";

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << '[' << chart[i][j] << ']';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    Example Exa1(6, 5, &chart);
    Exa1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to say since you didn't include the code that constructs an instance of `Example` and we have no idea what `chart` is. Please include a complete example that exhibits the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: The program [works here](https://godbolt.org/z/8nYc3EjPb). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: use std::vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that the type of `&chart` is `std::string (*)[7][7]` which cannot be implicitly converted to a `string**` and so the constructor `Example::Example(int i, int j,string **)` cannot be used. This is exactly what the mentioned error says:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'Example::Example(int, int, std::string (*)[7][7])'
   45 |     Example Exa1(6, 5, &chart);
```

To **solve** this make sure that `&chart` has the same type as the 3 parameter of your constructor.

Also it would be better to use `std::vector`.

```
class Example {
    int x, y;
    std::vector<std::vector<string>> chart;
public:

    Example(int i, int j,const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &arr);
    
};

Example::Example(int i, int j,const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &arr)
   :x(i),y(j),chart(arr) {
  
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> chart(7, std::vector<std::string>(7)); 
    //pass chart instead of &chart
    Example Exa1(6, 5, chart);

}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/za8Mhnbqa)

---

Or you can also use `std::array`

```
class Example {
    int x, y;
    std::array<std::array<std::string, 7>, 7> chart;
public:

    Example(int i, int j,const std::array<std::array<std::string, 7>, 7> &arr);
    
};

Example::Example(int i, int j,const std::array<std::array<std::string, 7>, 7> &arr)
   :x(i),y(j),chart(arr) {
  
}

int main() {

    std::array<std::array<std::string, 7>, 7> chart;
    //pass chart instead of &chart
    Example Exa1(6, 5, chart);

}
```

Comment: So how would I have the third parameter be the same as &chart? I thought string** was how.

Comment: @b23 See my updated answer where I added a [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/za8Mhnbqa) which uses `std::vector`.

Comment: is using a vector the only way? Is it impossible to pass a dynamically created 2d array as a class parameter by reference?

Comment: @b23 Using `std::vector` is the simplest and cleanest way of doing it. But if you want you can also use `std::array`. Also I wouldn't recommend using `new` and `delete` explicitly.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How do I do that? How do I do what I was trying to do with an array?

Comment: @b23 Check out my updated answer where I've shown(by adding a [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/14hh6qfqq)) how to use `std::array`.

Comment: This works with known dimensions, but is there a way to do this if we don't know them? The program is going to ask the user to give the dimensions as input at the start and then create the array dynamically, then later use it as a parameter for the class. That's one of the reasons why I wanted to pass the array by reference.

Comment: @b23 That is exactly why `std::vector` is preferred. In particular because using `std::vector` allows you to change the size of the vector dynamically meaning you can ask from user the size and then use that input size accordingly. Also, using `std::vector` you don't have to worry about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: So is this impossible to do with an array?

Comment: @b23 Yes because size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. This means that the size of an array cannot be taken from user in C++. Again this is why `std::vector` should be the preferred choice for your scenario.

Comment: @b23 You're welcome. Note also that `std::vector` is also sometimes called a *dynamic array* exactly because its size can be changed when needed unlike a `std::array` or a built in array.